# Matrix equations solving

Tags: equation-solving, matrix

can you explain me the easiest way for solving this matrix equation? I have this matrix:

`a={{-4,1,3,0},{-2,7,1,-1},{1,-1,9,-3},{-1,0,5,-10}`

and the Equation is:

`2a-x+IdentityMatrix[4]==0`

Where `x`  is the **Unknown Matrix**

or the better question apart from this upper exercise would be, how can i solve matrix equations that have this form `A+X=...(0, or any other matrix)`

Comment: So, try replacing `x` with `2 a + IdentityMatrix[4]`...

Comment: I know, thats the "common way", but is there like a command like at the polynomials `for example: Solve[x+1==0,x]` but just for matrix solving?

Comment: `Array[x, {4,4}] /. Solve[Flatten[
  Thread /@ Thread[2 a - Array[x, {4, 4}] + IdentityMatrix[4] == 0]], 
 Flatten@Array[x, {4, 4}]]` or `Solve[Flatten[
  Table[2 a[[i, j]] - x[i, j] + Boole[i == j] == 0, {i, 4}, {j, 4}]], 
 Flatten[Array[x, {4, 4}]]]`

Answer (score 2):

The following is a general technique, using `Solve`

```
a = {{-4, 1, 3, 0}, {-2, 7, 1, -1}, {1, -1, 9, -3}, {-1, 0, 5, -10}};
X = Array[x, {4, 4}]
sol = Solve[2 a - X + IdentityMatrix[4] == Array[0 &, {4, 4}], Flatten[X]]
X /. Flatten[sol] // MatrixForm
```